# jQuery - refresh dom when classes applied?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the user loads the page on a mobile device or desktop Im applying a class onto the body to control how the megamenu works, the problem is when adding the classes on this way nothing happens as I presume theyre not in the dom so not firing, is there a way around this?

```
if (Modernizr.mq('only all and (max-width: 599px)')) {
    $('body').removeClass('desktop').addClass('mobile');
}

if (Modernizr.mq('only all and (min-width: 600px)')) {
    $('body').removeClass('mobile').addClass('desktop');
}


$('.mobile .navigation nav > ul > li').on({
       mouseenter: function (e) {
          $(this).find('.dropdown').delay(200).slideDown();
       }
});

$('.desktop .navigation nav > ul > li').on({
      mouseenter: function (e) {
          $(this).find('.dropdown').delay(200).addClass("hovered");
      },
      mouseleave: function (e) {
          $(this).find('.dropdown').removeClass("hovered");
      }
});
```

Comment: have you tried wrapping the whole thing in a `$(document).ready`?

Comment: Doesnt fix the problem.. if the page loads with the desktop class applied and say I then change the screen size down to mobile the mobile function doesnt work and vice versa (I should probably note there is another bit of code that switches the classes around on screen resize)

Comment: Then you need an event that listens to browser resize and put all the code in there that you need to run again (you will probably want to throttle that so it doesn't fire multiple times while the user is still resizing)

Answer (score 0):

If i get i right your `if (Modernizr.mq('only all and (max-width: 599px)')) {` only checks for the mediaquery and has no event attached?!

If you want to check your width on resize of your browser try this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (Modernizr.mq('only all and (max-width: 599px)')) {
        $('body').removeClass('desktop').addClass('mobile');
    }

    if (Modernizr.mq('only all and (min-width: 600px)')) {
        $('body').removeClass('mobile').addClass('desktop');
    }
});
```